# Integrated News feed not displaying (ANDROID KITKAT)

Tags: java, android, json, xml, feed

SO I'm creating an application for dog lovers (University project) and I'm trying to create an integrated news feed that shows dog related news and when clicked takes the user to the website. I made a dummy application to test the system and it worked perfectly. as soon as I switched it over to my current Dog app it completely stopped working. The problem is that the Activity I use to display the list of articles shows absolutely nothing.

There are 2 activities here, a Links Activity and a newsItem Activity. The Links Activity is the main activity the page uses and displays the text in a certain way on the page. The newsItem Activity acts as a getter and works through a JSON file to find certain words in an array and parse them back to the application. I also use a localHost to host the JSON file.

If you guys can help me out here that would be incredible! I've hit a complete brick wall.

The Links_Activity Class is connected to the activity_links.xml file

The newsItem Class is connected to the Article.xml file

**Links_Activity Class**

```
   package uk.ac.napier.doggo;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;


import com.android.volley.DefaultRetryPolicy;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Links_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private List<newsItem> newsFeed = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_links);

        engine();
        addClickListener();

    }

    private void engine() {
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        JsonObjectRequest myReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                "http://10.0.2.2/news.json",
                null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray newsItems = response.getJSONArray("newsItems");

                            for (int i = 0; i < newsItems.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject temp = newsItems.getJSONObject(i);

                                String image = temp.getString("image");
                                String title = temp.getString("title");
                                String time = temp.getString("time");
                                String date = temp.getString("date");
                                String content = temp.getString("content");
                                String link = temp.getString("link");


                                newsFeed.add(new newsItem(title, content, date, time, link, image));

                            }
                        } catch(JSONException e){
                            Log.i("myTag", e.toString());
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.i("myTag", error.toString());
                    }
                });



        myReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                30*1000,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        queue.add(myReq);



        ArrayAdapter<newsItem> adapter = new customAdapter();

        ListView  newsItems = (ListView) (findViewById(R.id.newsItems));
        newsItems.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    private void addClickListener() {
        ListView newsItems = (ListView) (findViewById(R.id.newsItems));
        newsItems.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                newsItem currentItem = newsFeed.get(position);
                Intent i = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setData(Uri.parse(currentItem.getUrl()));
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }



        private class customAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<newsItem> {
                public customAdapter() {
            super(Links_Activity.this, R.layout.article, newsFeed);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if(convertView == null) {
                convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.article, parent, false);
            }

            newsItem currentItem = newsFeed.get(position);

            ImageView newsImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.leftIco);
            TextView heading = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.heading);
            TextView desc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.desc);

            heading.setText(currentItem.getNewsHeading());
            desc.setText(currentItem.getNewsDesc());

            Picasso.with(Links_Activity.this).load(currentItem.getImageURL()).into(newsImage);


            return convertView;
        }

    }

    public void Back(View view) {
        Intent startBackActivity = new Intent(this, Menu_Activity.class);
        startActivity(startBackActivity);
    }
}
```

**activity_links.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="News Feed"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

<TextView
    android:text="Articles Courtesy of Dogster.com"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:id="@+id/newsItems"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**newsItem Class**

```
package uk.ac.napier.doggo;

import java.util.PriorityQueue;

/**
 * Created by MarkB on 10/03/2017.
 */

public class newsItem {

    private String newsHeading;
    private String newsDesc;
    private String newsDescSmall;
    private String time;
    private String date;
    private String url;
    private String imageURL;

    public newsItem(String newsHeading, String newsDesc, String date,  String time, String url, String imageURL) {
        this.newsHeading = newsHeading;
        this.newsDesc = newsDesc;
        this.time = time;
        this.date = date;
        this.url = url;
        this.imageURL = imageURL;

        this.newsDescSmall = this.newsDesc.substring(0, 50) + "...";
    }

    public String getNewsHeading() {
        return newsHeading;
    }

    public String getNewsDesc() {
        return newsDesc;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public String getImageURL() {
        return imageURL;
    }
}
```

**article.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="10dp">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/leftIco"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:maxHeight="100dp"
    android:maxWidth="100dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:text="Heading Text"
    android:id="@+id/heading"
    android:scrollHorizontally="false"
    android:maxLines="100"
    android:ellipsize="none"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/leftIco"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/leftIco"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Description"
    android:id="@+id/desc"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="-3dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="26dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/leftIco"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/heading"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/heading"/>




</RelativeLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml for reference**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="uk.ac.napier.doggo">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">
</uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".Home_Screen_Activity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Details_Activity" />
        <activity android:name=".Menu_Activity" />
        <activity android:name=".Reminders_Activity" />
        <activity android:name=".Health_Tracker_Activity" />
        <activity android:name=".Routes_Activity" />
        <activity android:name=".Route_Complete_Activity" />
        <activity android:name=".History_Activity" />
        <activity android:name=".Links_Activity" >

        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".TimePopUp_Activity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.CustomTheme" >
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Finally the news.JSON file**

```
{"newsItems":[
{
"image": "http://www.dogster.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/16806949_152063731974308_6992949846293798966_n-Cropped.jpg",
"title": "Artist Arien Smith Imagines Disney Princesses With Service Dogs",
"time": "10:00am ",
"date": "22 Jun ",
"content": "So far, the artist has drawn Cinderella and Snow White with     service dogs, with the hope of raising awareness and money for his own helper.",
"link": "http://www.dogster.com/lifestyle/artist-arien-smith-imagines-disney-princesses-with-service-dogs"
},
{
"image": "http://www.dogster.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Stalking-predatory-hero.png",
"title": "Is Your Dog a Bully?",
"time":"12:00am ",
"date":"Jun 12",
"content": "Dogs who bully not only start fights, but they can turn timid dogs into bullies themselves. Let's look at the signs of bullying and how to help your dog stop this behavior.",
"link": "http://www.dogster.com/lifestyle/is-your-dog-a-bully"
}
]
}
```

Comment: was there any useful errors?

Comment: Does this code even build? The `customAdapter` method looks suspicious.

Comment: Code Builds fine and sorry but It doesn't display any errors that are related. I think it may have something to do with maybe the local host and the JSON object request

Comment: Why not make sure it's about the JSON by printing the said JSON in your `onResponse` ? Pinpointing what the problem is would be a good first step towards debugging the problem.

Comment: do I do something similar to what I did with the catch exception to do that? I'm still a noob at Android

Comment: put a log in your for loop : `Log.i("Title", title);`.

Comment: no errors displayed. outputs the information that was stored in the JSON file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never called `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

```
        newsFeed.add(new newsItem(title, content, date, time, link, image));
    }  // end loop
    // notify the adapter to display the new data 
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
} catch(JSONException e){
    Log.i("myTag", e.toString());
}
```

**However**, you have an ArrayAdapter, so just add to that, not the Arraylist then you don't need to notify

```
        // See here
        adapter.add(new newsItem(title, content, date, time, link, image));
    }  // end loop
} catch(JSONException e){
    Log.i("myTag", e.toString());
}
```

---

Some re-arrangement of your code that should work.

```
public class LinksActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
  implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, Response.ErrorListener {

    private List<NewsItem> newsFeed = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayAdapter<NewsItem>  adapter;

    // Moved the Volley response to top-level
    private Response.Listener<JSONObject>  newsListener = new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()  {        

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                JSONArray newsItems = response.getJSONArray("newsItems");

                for (int i = 0; i < newsItems.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject temp = newsItems.getJSONObject(i);

                    String image = temp.getString("image");
                    String title = temp.getString("title");
                    String time = temp.getString("time");
                    String date = temp.getString("date");
                    String content = temp.getString("content");
                    String link = temp.getString("link");


                    newsFeed.add(new newsItem(title, content, date, time, link, image));
                }

                // Important!
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            } catch(JSONException e){
                Log.i("myTag", e.toString());
            }
        }
    };

    // This is Volley's error listener over the entire Activity
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Log.i("myTag", error.toString());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_links);

        // Set and define the List and Adapter here
        ListView  newsItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.newsItems);
        newsItems.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        adapter = new CustomAdapter();
        newsItems.setAdapter(adapter);

        engine();
    }

    private void engine() {
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        // Now this method is much 'cleaner'
        JsonObjectRequest myReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                "http://10.0.2.2/news.json",
                null, 
                newsListener, this);

        myReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                30*1000,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        queue.add(myReq);
    }

    // The Activity itself handles the clicking
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        NewsItem currentItem = newsFeed.get(position);
        Intent i = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(currentItem.getUrl()));
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show me on the Links_Activity where that would go?

Comment: I don't fully understand where exactly I put that and what to do with that information. I'm very new to android development

Comment: It's not Android specific. It's just java. You already have `newsFeed.add` . Replace it

Comment: I know this is very frustrating but you have to understand I am a complete noob. Can you please just show me the code and where it fits into it? like actually write the code because I don't understand the terminology or how any of these methods all work.

Comment: Basically, you added to a list successfully, yes. But Android doesn't update the ArrayAdapter unless you explicitly tell it to. Thus `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` needs to be after that `for` loop within `onResponse`. You can see my answer for the relevant pieces

Comment: hmm are there some syntax errors in there? there are a lot of red lines all over my code

Comment: I did rename `NewsItem` because class names should always be capitalized. But 1) I have not tested this, no. It could very well be very, very wrong. 2) You really shouldn't copy code off the internet unless you understand what it does / tries to do

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137856/discussion-between-mark-barton-and-cricket-007).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

pass the array items to the adapter:

```
customAdapter adapter = new customAdapter(this, newsFeed);
ListView  newsItems = (ListView) (findViewById(R.id.newsItems));
newsItems.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Now in adapter class use:

```
private List<newsItem> newsFeed_list ;

   public customAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<newsItem> items) {
        super(context, items);
        this.newsFeed_list = items;
    }
```

And get the object using:

```
newsItem currentItem = newsFeed_list.get(position);
```